# Does TLS-OBC only improve security of Web Browsers? Does it improve the security of SSH?

Tags: web-application, authentication, tls, web-browser, ssh

I'm studying the [TLS-OBC extension](http://www.browserauth.net) and would like to know if it improves security of non Web-based protocols?

Specifically, would it be of any benefit to SSH clients? (version 1 or version 2.x/secsh)

I'm just trying to understand the scope of applicability of this technology

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSH does not rely on SSL/TLS (see [RFC 4253](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4253)). OpenSSH relies on the OpenSSL library, but that's just because it reuses some of the cryptographic functions, which are common to the two protocols (OpenSSL does far more than SSL/TLS).

Therefore, you wouldn't be able to use TLS-OBS as such with SSH.

Would you want to generate a new key-pair every time you log on to a new SSH server, in a similar way to what's suggested in TLS-OBS? Possibly, but you wouldn't necessarily need a new extension to achieve the same goal. You might as well use the current methods: generate an SSH key-pair and add the public key to the authorized keys in your account the first time you log on.

Answer (score 1):

OpenSSL is mostly two libraries and their associated includes. `libcrypto` is a generic cryptographic library, implementing stuff such as chaining modes, block ciphers and cryptographic hashes. The second component of OpenSSL is the `libssl` library, implementing the SSL and TLS protocols.

The SSH protocol is not based on SSL/TLS, and OpenSSH only uses the libcrypto component of OpenSSL.